# 'npm run serve' is not initiallizing project in browser

Tags: powershell, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli, windows-terminal

I am running 'npm run serve' command to execute my vue project in browser . But it is not giving any output or error it just keep running
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yer2l.png)
it just stucks here only
I have tried every thing I have restarted my system and reinstalled vue-cli also but it it didn't worked.
I was running perfectly fine yesterday but today it's not working in fact it wasted my whole day

What did I try

Execute 'npm run serve' cmd

What I Expect

To open my project in Browser

Answer (score 0):

`npm run serve` will run the built version of your project. It sound to me like you want to run it locally in the browser (for dev and testing) and should use `npm run dev`.

`npm run serve` will only serve the output of a `npm run build` command, and is usually only run after deploying to an actual server.

Answer (score -1):

```
{
  "name": "fer-07-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --fix --ext .js,.jsx .",
    "init-project": "npm install && npm-run-all init:*",
    "init:dirs": "mkdirp dist src/sass src/css src/vendor src/images src/js",
    "init:files": "touch README.md src/index.html src/sass/style.scss src/js/script.js",
    "init:gitignore": "curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/gitignore/master/Node.gitignore -o .gitignore",
    "init:gitignore:custom": "echo \"dist\" >> .gitignore",
    "test": "npm-run-all test:*",
    "test:html": "globstar nu-html-checker dist/*.html",
    "test:js": "eslint src/js/ --fix",
    "test:scss": "stylelint src/sass/",
    "build": "npm-run-all build:* test",
    "build:clean": "mkdirp dist && rm -r dist && mkdirp dist",
    "build:copy": "copyfiles -a -u 1 -e \"**/sass/**/*\" -e \"**/.gitkeep\" \"src/**/*\" dist",
    "build:sass": "node-sass --output-style compact -o dist/css src/sass",
    "build:autoprefixer": "globstar autoprefixer-cli \"dist/css/*.css\"",
    "build-dev": "npm-run-all build-dev:sass build:autoprefixer",
    "build-dev:sass": "node-sass --output-style expanded --source-map true -o dist/css src/sass",
    "server": "json-server --port 3131 --no-cors --delay 250 --watch dist/db/app.json",
    "watch": "npm-run-all build build-dev -p watch:* server",
    "watch:browsersync": "browser-sync start --server dist --files \"dist/**/*\" --ignore \"dist/db/**/*\"",
    "watch:sassprefixer": "onchange \"src/sass/**/*.scss\" -- npm run build-dev",
    "watch:copy": "onchange -e \"**/sass/**/*\" -e \"**/.gitkeep\" \"src/**/*\" -- copyfiles -a -u 1 {{changed}} dist"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "flatpickr": "^4.6.9",
    "json-server": "^0.16.3",
    "rangeslider-pure": "^0.4.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer-cli": "^1.0.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.3",
    "copyfiles": "^2.1.0",
    "eslint": "^5.14.1",
    "globstar": "^1.0.0",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "nu-html-checker": "^0.1.0",
    "onchange": "^5.2.0",
    "stylelint": "^9.10.1",
    "stylelint-scss": "^3.5.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer to the question posed? If so how? Perhaps you should follow this up, now I've formatted it for you, with some body text, via the [Edit] button!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).